# Python 3.10 - How to properly type hint __add__ in a dataclass that inherits Generic[TypeVar]?

Tags: oop, type-hinting, python-typing, python-3.10, magic-methods

I have this package called [totemp](https://github.com/eddyyxxyy/ToTemp/tree/Develop-0.5.0) that provides convertions between temperature scales. It's currently in development and I just don't know how to type hint the add magic method.

There are 8 dataclasses, Celsius, Fahrenheit, Delisle, Kelvin, Newton, Rankine, Réaumur and Romer.

Celsius class with dunder add and one of the convertion methods (@no_type_check to prevent mypy from not letting me commit).

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, no_type_check

TEMP = TypeVar('TEMP', int, float)  # TEMP must be int or float


@dataclass
class Celsius(Generic[TEMP]):
    """..."""

    __value: TEMP
    __symbol: str = field(compare=False, repr=False, default='ºC')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.__value}{self.__symbol}'

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'Celsius({self.__value})'

    @no_type_check
    def __add__(self, other):
        match str(type(other)):
            case "<class 'totemp.temperature_types.Celsius'>":
                return Celsius(self.__value + other.value)
            case _:
                try:
                    other = other.to_celsius()
                    return Celsius(self.__value + other.value)
                except AttributeError as error:
                    print(
                        f'\033[31;1mAttributeError: {error}.\n    ' +
                        f"Cause: '{other}' is not a temperature scale.\033[m"
                    )

    def to_fahrenheit(self) -> 'Fahrenheit[TEMP]':
        """
        Returns a Fahrenheit object which contains the class attribute "value"
        with the result from the conversion typed the same as the attribute.

        Returns
        -------
        Fahrenheit[TEMP]
        """
        fahrenheit = type(self.__value)(self.__value * 9 / 5 + 32)
        return Fahrenheit(fahrenheit)
```

I tried creating an abstract class, but that didn't worked well, didn't even know what I was doing tbh. Tried read Python docs, but I had no response for what i'm trying to do, couldn't find any solution for myself. Thought about NewType, but after reading about in the docs, didn't understood it very well too.

Thought about doing something like:

```py
GenericType = NewType('Temp', Union[Celsius, Fahrenheit, ...])
```

But ended up with more mypy errors that I couldn't deal with.

**How do I properly type hint dunder add and other magic methods (such as gt, lt, e.g.)?**

Comment: Suggestions/solutions hinge on a few basic assumptions about your classes. And some of your code raises questions for me. Do you actually need your classes (e.g. `Celcius`) to be **generic** in terms of the type of the actual value? You are constraining the generic type parameter `TEMP` to `int` or `float`, yet going through the source code, I could not find an actual use for this. Why don't you just say the value is simply a `float` (considering the Python type system will always accept `int` in its place)? Is this a relic or does/will this serve a purpose?

Comment: I checked out your the code in the latest dev branch of your repo. You have the `rounded` method to create a new instance of the same class, but with an integer value. I can kind of see the reason, if you want a nice display in the string representation(s). But I still don't understand the purpose of making your classes generic and less so of making this `int` vs. `float` distinction with regards to typing. The user can pass an instance of either one to the constructor. Does it matter, which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got lost in more and more things I thought might be optimized with the code, so I ended up placing a [merge request](https://github.com/eddyyxxyy/ToTemp/pull/22) for your current dev branch.

To quickly answer the basic idea relevant for this particular question:

I don't think the class should be generic. I don't understand the purpose of that.

A base class is *definitely* a good idea (considering the DRY principle). Making it abstract, you could enforce a `convert_to` method for all subclasses, which you could then utilize in your numeric operand dunder methods like `__add__`.

Then typing would become fairly easy with bounded type variables:

```py
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from typing import Any, ClassVar, TypeVar


T = TypeVar("T", bound="AbstractTemperature")


class AbstractTemperature(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, value: float) -> None:
        self._value = value

    @property
    def value(self) -> float:
        return self._value

    @abstractmethod
    def convert_to(self, temp_cls: type[T]) -> T:
        ...

    def __add__(self: T, other: Any) -> T:
        cls = self.__class__
        try:
            if isinstance(other, AbstractTemperature):
                return cls(self._value + other.convert_to(cls).value)
            return cls(self._value + other)
        except TypeError:
            return NotImplemented
```